# Should I query the OS before using LocalFree/HeapFree, from FormatMessage, with Windows 7/8.1 and Windows 10?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) (FormatMessage function):

> **Windows 10:**
>
> > **LocalFree** is not in the modern SDK, so it cannot be used
> >     to free the result buffer. Instead, use **HeapFree** (GetProcessHeap(),
> >     allocatedMessage). In this case, this is the same as calling LocalFree
> >     on memory.

I don't know how to use HeapFree, but I wanna run the app in Windows 7, Windows 8/8.1 and Windows 10, but I am currently using just LocalFree and It is working.

This is my code:

```
VOID ShowErrorMsg(DWORD messageId)
{
    DWORD flags=FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS;
    DWORD languageID = LANG_USER_DEFAULT;
    LPWSTR errorMsg;
    DWORD size = 0;

    FormatMessageW(flags, NULL, messageId, languageID, (LPTSTR)&errorMsg, size, NULL);

    wprintf(L"\n%s", errorMsg);

    LocalFree(errorMsg);

}
```

My question is, should I use functions like `IsWindows7SP1OrGreater`, `IsWindows8Point1OrGreater` and `IsWindows10OrGreater`, [from Version Helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx), before calling `LocalFree` or `HeapFree`?

If I have to call `HeapFree`, can anyone give me an example on how to use it?

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation you quoted gave you an example. Just replace `LocalFree(errorMsg)` with `HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), errorMsg)`. Also, your typecast is wrong. You should be using `(LPWSTR)&errorMsg` instead of `(LPTSTR)&errorMsg`. And you are not checking the return value of `FormatMessageW()` for error before using and freeing `errorMsg`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used `LPTSTR` because the doc says I must cast the pointer to an `LPTSTR.` So, do I have to query for the OS version?

Comment: no - you not need query os version. the `LocalFree` is exist (exported) in all os version. the `LocalFree is not in the modern SDK` think mean that this api simply *not declared* in some SDK (strange - in 14393 still declared).

Comment: @Checho you are not calling the `TCHAR` version of `FormatMessage()` so using a `TCHAR` typecast is wrong. You are using the `WCHAR` version directly, so you need a `WCHAR` typecast. The documentation is written with `TCHAR` in mind.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, got it and fixed it. What is not clear for me is if I have to query the OS. According to your first answer, I think I have to, but RbMm said I don't have to. Thank you for answering to you both.

Comment: allocate some variable length buffer inside function and return it to caller, and than caller o free the returned buffer, call the `LocalFree` function - this is very common windows style. look for example [CryptDecodeObjectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379912(v=vs.85).aspx) or [ConvertSidToStringSid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376399(v=vs.85).aspx) - here nothing said about SDK and `LocalFree` strange

Comment: @Checho I didn't say anything one way or another about it. The answer is no, you do not need to check the OS version. If your compiler's SDK recognizes `LocalFree` then use it. Otherwise use `HeapFree` instead. They are the same thing in this situation.

Comment: Comparing the "requirements" sections in the documentation for FormatMessage, LocalFree, and HeapFree suggests that the only time you need to use HeapFree instead of LocalFree is if you are building for Windows Phone.  I'm not sure whether that's actually true, but it's what the documentation says. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I would like to mark an answer, but I need you to answer the question so I can do it.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Windows 7 doesn't support modern apps anyway. Why are you using the modern SDK to write Windows 7 apps? If you are writing a plain Win32 desktop app, then just call `LocalFree`. it has been available to Win32 desktop apps since 1992.

Comment: in sdk `LocalFree` conditionally defined as `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP | WINAPI_PARTITION_SYSTEM)` so this probably hint where it used

Comment: My fault. Got confused about the Windows 10 title, but you all clarified my mistake.

Comment: You linked to the documentation, that has a full answer to your question. Why are you *still* asking this question, including the link to the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Modern" here means WinRT/Metro/Modern/Store application. `LocalFree` exists on every version of Windows and can be used by Classic/Desktop applications on all Windows versions.

Comment: The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366730(v=vs.85).aspx) for `LocalFree()` does recommend to use the "heap functions" though. If the local functions really have more overhead, that would be a valid reason to prefer the heap functions, but I don't know if this statement is true.

Comment: @zett42 but when the documentation tells you to free with a specific function then that overrides everything else. You don't know if Windows 7 treats LocalFree==HeapFree etc.